# How to print a json in Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

Am getting a json from an api, how to print the json using Smarty.

Json format

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "jinu",
        "last_name": "mk",
        "loginid": "jinu@amt.in",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "c964ef415f157ddd99173f5b481ee1e3",
        "user_type": 1,
        "last_login_date": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "avatar second",
        "last_name": "test",
        "loginid": "avatar2@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "ec40f5feda8643135bc20be44f897b03",
        "user_type": "3",
        "last_login_date": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "avatar testing admin",
        "last_name": "amt 1",
        "loginid": "avatar@amt.in",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "ec40f5feda8643135bc20be44f897b03",
        "user_type": 1,
        "last_login_date": null
    }
]
```

I have tired the following foreach but its not printing anything.

```
{foreach from=$games item=foo}
     <li>{$foo.first_name}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 possible solutions.

**First solution**

in PHP you use:

```
$data = '[
    {
        "first_name": "jinu",
        "last_name": "mk",
        "loginid": "jinu@amt.in",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "c964ef415f157ddd99173f5b481ee1e3",
        "user_type": 1,
        "last_login_date": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "avatar second",
        "last_name": "test",
        "loginid": "avatar2@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "ec40f5feda8643135bc20be44f897b03",
        "user_type": "3",
        "last_login_date": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "avatar testing admin",
        "last_name": "amt 1",
        "loginid": "avatar@amt.in",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "ec40f5feda8643135bc20be44f897b03",
        "user_type": 1,
        "last_login_date": null
    }
]';


$smarty->assign('games',$data);
```

In Smarty you use:

```
{foreach from=$games|json_decode item=foo}
     <li>{$foo->first_name}</li>
{/foreach}
```

However I'm not sure in this case if `json_decode` is run on `$games` just once or on each invocation.

**Second solution**

In PHP you use:

```
$data = '[
    {
        "first_name": "jinu",
        "last_name": "mk",
        "loginid": "jinu@amt.in",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "c964ef415f157ddd99173f5b481ee1e3",
        "user_type": 1,
        "last_login_date": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "avatar second",
        "last_name": "test",
        "loginid": "avatar2@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "ec40f5feda8643135bc20be44f897b03",
        "user_type": "3",
        "last_login_date": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "avatar testing admin",
        "last_name": "amt 1",
        "loginid": "avatar@amt.in",
        "timezone": "5.5",
        "team_id": "ec40f5feda8643135bc20be44f897b03",
        "user_type": 1,
        "last_login_date": null
    }
]';



$smarty->assign('games',json_decode($data));
```

In Smarty file:

```
{foreach from=$games item=foo}
     <li>{$foo->first_name}</li>
{/foreach}
```

I always recommend using second method, because if possible in Smarty you should avoid using any calculations and just display data.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
{foreach from=$games item=foo}
     {assign var=bar value=$foo|json_decode:1}
     <li>{$bar.first_name}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to convert it to array then it will be much easier for you to loop through and print it

Say for you are getting your json in a variable named $response

```
// Convert to array
{$response|json_decode}
```

You will be getting an array now and you can loop through the array using {foreach}

After converting to array it will be easier for you to loop as foreach work for array and not for json output