# Decode json in Smarty

Tags: php, json, smarty

I have a url I'm defining in my controller like this:

```
$musicList = "http://website.com/search?q=$artist&results=30";
```

This will create a json file with 30 result from a artist. In my template file I want to decode this json and display twi values from it. The json look like this:

```
[
{
artist: "Rihanna",
title: "Rihanna - Diamonds",
trid: "ID"
},
{
artist: "Rihanna",
title: "S&M",
trid: "ID"
},
```

But I can't figure out how to print them in the template file, the following code gives me nothing:

```
        {foreach from=$musicList item=entry}
        {assign var=song value=$entry|json_decode:1}
        <pre>
            {$song|@print_r}
        </pre>
        {/foreach}
```

I use smarty in PHPFox if that has anything to do with solving this.

Comment: decode the array in the controller, then you are just iterating a regular php array in the view

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a json in Smarty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909142/how-to-print-a-json-in-smarty)

Comment: You have exact solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24909960/3593996

Comment: Thanks guys! Didn't get that result when googling!

Comment: Ok, the linked method did not work...

Answer (score 2):

The method i mentioned really works.

If in php file you have:

```
$data = array(
    array(

        'artist' => "Rihanna",
        'title'  => "Rihanna - Diamonds",
        'trid'   => "ID"
    ),
    array(

        'artist' => "Rihanna",
        'title'  => "S&M",
        'trid'   => "ID"
    ),        
);


$x = json_encode($data);
$smarty->assign('musicList', $x);
```

and in Smarty you have:

```
{foreach from=$musicList|json_decode item=song}
    <pre>
            {$song->artist} {$song->title} {$song->trid}
    </pre>
{/foreach}
```

You will get desired result:

```
Rihanna Rihanna - Diamonds ID            
Rihanna S&M ID
```

Of course you need to be sure you have valid Json data (the code you pasted is a fragment of Json I think)

**EDIT - code with real data**

In PHP file:

```
$smarty->assign('musicList', file_get_contents('http://f.cl.ly/items/1C1P2v1U1i1a3i181a0T/search.json'));
```

In Smarty file - the same as I already told

Result is still as expected - no errors or warnings

Comment: I get this error: 
Notice: Use of undefined constant trid - assumed 'trid'
And here is the json file: http://cl.ly/code/3C2x3a2C2D3j/search.json

Comment: @AlexanderAhlsen Everything is working fine - look at edited answer

Comment: If I try to add a array (just copying direcly what you wrote) I get even more errors like this:

Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
Notice: Use of undefined constant trid - assumed 'trid'
Notice: Use of undefined constant title - assumed 'title'
Notice: Use of undefined constant artist - assumed 'artist'

I use smarty in PHPFox.

Comment: @AlexanderAhlsen You are doing probably something wrong. Edit your question and put in your code exact code from PHP how you set data and exact code from Smarty TPL file. You should also add information which Smarty version you use

Comment: That is my exact code, could it have somethibg to do with PHPFox?

Comment: @AlexanderAhlsen What's your exact code? You haven't published any exact code you use. Look again at my edit in my answer and put only this part in PHP - it loads data from remote server. You can't put Json string into PHP. You are doing everything in wrong way. Analyse my answer again

Answer (score -1):

I got this working by doing the following in my PHP file:

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://labs.echonest.com/Uploader/search?q=$artist&results=30");
        $json = json_decode($url, true);

        $trackname = array();
        $url = array();
        $i = 0;
        if($artist) {
            foreach ($json as $track) {
            $trackname = $track['title'];
            $url = $track['trid'];
            $artists[] = $track['artist'];
            $tester[] = "<a href='$url'>$trackname</a>";
            $i++;
        }

        } else {
                echo Phpfox::getPhrase('lastfm.not_connected');
        }
```

Then I assigned it to my template:

```
'songs' => $tester,
```

And called it like this:

```
{foreach from=$songs item=song}{$song}<br/>{/foreach}
```

Comment: Sorry, there's no Smarty here. You have PHP code that you haven't posted in your question. It's completely different than what you ask and what you explained

Comment: I had to change it, so that's why it's different from the code I fist posted. @MarcinNabiałek wow.